# search and get distenic result base on create_at in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I store data in the elastic search like this:

```
{
"_index": "my_index",
"_type": "doc",
"_id": "6lDquGEBFRQVe0x93eHk",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"Barcode": "6947503728601",
"category":"pen",
"name": "panter",
"price":"4$",
"created_at": "1519225855"
}
}
```

Each data set has a barcode. For example, all panter pen have "6947503728601" as a barcode but they have different `created_at` values.

I want to search for partial barcode number(69475) and get all matching docs that are unique in barcode field with the latest one of them based on the `created_at` value (I want to get latest document data for each barcode number)

1. How can I implement the search?
2. is my algorithm correct?

Comment: you can use search with "Barcode" field with sorting on "created_at" field and optionally you can also set the size parameter to 1

Comment: excuse me @torzonhot i changed my question for clarification.